# A Question about Dense subsets

Tags: functional-analysis

Let  $V=C^1[0,1]$ and

$X=(C([0,1],||\;||_\infty)$ and $Y=(C[0,1],||\;||_2)$.

which  of the following is correct

(a) Dense  in $X$  but NOT in $Y$

(b) Dense  in $Y$  but NOT in $X$

(c) Dense in BOTH $X,Y$

(d) Dense in neither $X$ and $Y$

The answer is (c)

But I don't have Idea about this ?Any Hint is helpful

Thank you so mush for you all time

Comment: Since $C([0,1])\varsupsetneq C^1([0,1])$, the question doesn't make sense.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos....You are totally correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have switches $C[0,1]$ and $C^{1}[0,1]$ in the question. Once you correct the question the result follows by polynomial approximation (wierstrass' Theorem) and the fact that $\sqrt {\int (f-g)^{2}} \leq ||f-g||_{\infty }$.